# Configure Jenkins job to install Docker via ansible

Tags: jenkins, docker, ansible

I am struggling to fix an issue while I am configuring jenkins job to install docker containers via ansible

Error is:

> {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "`docker-py` doesn't seem to be installed, but is required for the Ansible Docker module."}

I have installed docker-py in Jenkins host where ansible is running. I guess I don't want to do any configs in remote machines (where docker container is going to deploy).

When I execute a `find` command I get the following output:

```
$ sudo find  /  -name docker.py -print
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/docker.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/cloud/docker/docker.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/docker.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/cloud/docker/docker.py
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/docker.py
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/cloud/docker/docker.py
```

I just want to know where is the location ansible is searching for Docker.py?

Comment: Issue is figured out.Docker-py need to be installed in client side.On the machine that we are going to deploy packages and we have to set the approprate permission for /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/

Answer (score 1):

`docker.py` – is an ansible module `docker` that use [docker-py](https://github.com/docker/docker-py) under the hood.
Check that you really have `docker-py` installed.

Comment: docker-py needs to be installed on the target host, not the source host.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install docker-py on the target host

```
- name: install docker-py
  pip:
    name: docker-py
    state: present
```